# Automatically reselect a dropdown Option with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am hoping someone can help.

My code is below and what I am hoping for is when the user submits the form, the option value they selected remains at the top of the drop down list.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/reps.php'); ?>
<?php function GetPercent ($amount, $total) 
{
    $count1 = $amount / $total;
    $count2 = $count1 * 100;
    $count = number_format($count2, 0);
    return $count;
}
$countdate = time();
?>
<?php

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

$maxRows_orders = 10;
$pageNum_orders = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_orders'])) {
  $pageNum_orders = $_GET['pageNum_orders'];
}
$startRow_orders = $pageNum_orders * $maxRows_orders;

mysql_select_db($database_reps, $reps);
$query_orders = "SELECT
orders.ID AS ID,
customers.`Name` AS customerName,
products.ProductName AS product,
orders.Quantity AS Quantity,
orders.SalesPrice AS SalesPrice,
orders.Price AS Price,
orders.paid AS paid,
orders.AgeOfPayment AS AgeOfPayment,
orders.orderDate AS orderDate,
products.Price AS productPrice,
staff.StaffName AS staffMember,
orders.bonus AS bonus
FROM
orders
INNER JOIN staff AS staff ON orders.staffMember = staff.ID
INNER JOIN products AS products ON orders.product = products.ID
INNER JOIN customers AS customers ON orders.customerName = customers.ID 
WHERE
1 = 1 ";

//The above where makes the where true

// The below takes the customer name from the select input and filters based on selection. Filters the order by

if (isset($_GET['customerName2']) && $_GET['customerName2'] != 'FALSE' ) 
{
$query_orders .= "AND customerName = '" .$_GET['customerName2']."' ";
}

// This makes sure the product is not false and filters

if (isset($_GET['product']) && $_GET['product'] != 'FALSE') 
{
$query_orders .= "AND product = '" .$_GET['product']."' ";
}

// The below filters hte Customer Name

if (isset($_GET['customerName'])&& $_GET['customerName'] != 'FALSE') {
$query_orders .= "ORDER BY '".$_GET['customerName']."' ";
}


echo "$query_orders <br /> <br />";

$query_limit_orders = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_orders, $startRow_orders, $maxRows_orders);
$orders = mysql_query($query_limit_orders, $reps) or die(mysql_error());
$row_orders = mysql_fetch_assoc($orders);


if (isset($_GET['totalRows_orders'])) {
  $totalRows_orders = $_GET['totalRows_orders'];
} else {
  $all_orders = mysql_query($query_orders);
  $totalRows_orders = mysql_num_rows($all_orders);
}
$totalPages_orders = ceil($totalRows_orders/$maxRows_orders)-1;

$queryString_orders = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_orders") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_orders") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_orders = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_orders = sprintf("&totalRows_orders=%d%s", $totalRows_orders, $queryString_orders);

$paid = $row_orders['paid'];

mysql_select_db($database_reps, $reps);
$query_customers = "SELECT Name, ID FROM customers WHERE Status = 'Active'";
$customers = mysql_query($query_customers, $reps) or die(mysql_error());
$row_customers = mysql_fetch_assoc($customers);
$totalRows_customers = mysql_num_rows($customers);

mysql_select_db($database_reps, $reps);
$query_products = "SELECT * FROM products";
$products = mysql_query($query_products, $reps) or die(mysql_error());
$row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products);
$totalRows_products = mysql_num_rows($products);


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php


require_once("models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}
require_once("models/header.php");

?>
</head>

<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='top'>
  <div id='logo'></div>
</div>
<div id='content'>
  <div id='left-nav'>
    <?php include("left-nav.php"); ?>
  </div>
  <div id='main'> <?php echo " Hi, $loggedInUser->displayname. Here is where you will be able to view orders from a managers perspective. " ?>
  <div id = "filtertable">
<FORM METHOD="GET" ACTION="<?php   ?>">
  <table border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
      <td align="center">Order By</td>
      <td> <select name="customerName">
<option value="FALSE">Select how to Order By</option>
<option value="ID">Order ID</option>
<option value="customerName">Customer Name</option>
<option value="product">Product</option>
<option value="orderDate">Order Date</option>
<option value="paid">Paid?</option>
</select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Customer Name</td>
            <td><select name="customerName2">
               <option value="FALSE" >Select the Customer Name</option>
                 <?php 
do {  
?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_customers['ID']?>" ><?php echo $row_customers['Name'];?></option>
              <?php
} while ($row_customers = mysql_fetch_assoc($customers));
?>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
    <td align="center">Product</td>
    <td><select name="product">
  <option value="FALSE" >Select a Product</option>
        <?php 
do {  
?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row_products['ID']?>" >
      <?php echo $row_products['ProductName']?>
      </option>
      <?php
} while ($row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products));
?>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
    <td align="center">Order Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="25" /></td>
  </tr>
    <td align="center">Paid?</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="25" />
 </td>
  </tr>

    <td colspan="2" align="center">
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit Filter" NAME="B1" />    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <P>&nbsp;</P>
</FORM>

  </div>


    <div id ="orderstable">
      <table border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
          <th>Order ID</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Sales Price (€)</th>
          <th>Total Sale (€)</th>
          <th>List Price (€)</th>
          <th>Price Difference (€)</th>
          <th>% Difference</th>
          <th>Sold By</th>
          <th>Order Date</th>
          <th>Age of Payment</th>
          <th>Paid?</th>
          <th>Bonus %</th>
          <th>Bonus Amount (€)</th>
        </tr>
        <?php do { ?>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_orders['ID']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_orders['customerName']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_orders['product']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_orders['Quantity']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo "€"; echo number_format($row_orders['SalesPrice'], 2); ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php $first_multiply = $row_orders['Quantity'];
                                               $second_multiply = $row_orders['SalesPrice'];
                                               $multiply_total = $first_multiply *  $second_multiply;
                                               echo "€"; echo number_format(($multiply_total) , 2); ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo "€"; echo number_format($row_orders['Price'] ,2); ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo "€"; $first_number = $row_orders['Price']; 
                                                $second_number = $row_orders['SalesPrice'];
                                                $sum_total = $second_number - $first_number;
                                                echo number_format(($sum_total) ,2); ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php $percent = GetPercent($sum_total, $row_orders['Price']);
            echo $percent."%"; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_orders['staffMember']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', $row_orders['orderDate']); ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php 
      $currentorderdate = $countdate - $row_orders['orderDate'];
      $age = ($currentorderdate / 86400);
      $ageoforder = round($age, 0);
      echo $ageoforder;
      ?> day(s)</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php 
            if ($row_orders['paid'] == Yes) {
                echo $row_orders['paid'];
            } else {
                echo "No";
            }
            ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php 
            echo $row_orders['bonus']; ?>%</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php
            $bonustotal = (($multiply_total/100) * ($row_orders['bonus']));
        if ($percent > 0 && $ageoforder-1 < 90 ) {
         echo "€"; echo number_format($bonustotal ,2);
        } else {
          echo "€"; echo 0;
        }
      ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } while ($row_orders = mysql_fetch_assoc($orders));?>
      </table>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_orders > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_orders=%d%s", $currentPage, 0, $queryString_orders); ?>">First</a>
        <?php } // Show if not first page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_orders > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_orders=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_orders - 1), $queryString_orders); ?>">Previous</a>
        <?php } // Show if not first page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_orders < $totalPages_orders) { // Show if not last page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_orders=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_orders, $pageNum_orders + 1), $queryString_orders); ?>">Next</a>
        <?php } // Show if not last page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_orders < $totalPages_orders) { // Show if not last page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_orders=%d%s", $currentPage, $totalPages_orders, $queryString_orders); ?>">Last</a>
        <?php } // Show if not last page ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div id ="bottompart">
  <div id='bottom'></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html><?php
mysql_free_result($orders);

mysql_free_result($staff);

mysql_free_result($products);
?>
```

Comment: Why do you open and close so many `<?php` tags at the top of the page? Anyways, you should really split your code on different layers, the way it currently is is so hard to read / reuse / maintain.

Comment: Its how im used to. Learning at the minute so when i get better at this im sure ill cut down on alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to show the selected value of the user in the select list than you can use an `if` condition to echo `selected`

```
<?php
   $dynamic_val = /* Save the value if you call from db, or by using $_POST */;
?>
<select>
   <option value="1" <?php echo sel_opt(1, $dynamic_val); ?>></option>
   <option value="2" <?php echo sel_opt(2, $dynamic_val); ?>></option>
   <option value="3" <?php echo sel_opt(3, $dynamic_val); ?>></option>
</select>

<?php
   function sel_opt($opt, $val) {
     if($opt == $val) {
       return 'selected';
     }
   }
?>
```

> This won't literally shift the option to the top of the list, instead
>   it will select the user selected option

Comment: @RichieAnderson ;) you can use that function with any select in your website

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in there

```
<option value="FALSE" <?php echo isSelected("FALSE"); ?>>Select how to Order By</option>
<option value="ID" <?php echo isSelected("ID"); ?>>Order ID</option>
//so on....

function isSelected($term) {
   if(isset($_GET['customerName']) && $term == $_GET['customerName']) {
       return 'selected="selected"';
   }
}
```